# How to retain the older database after the android app is upgraded to new version?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I just want the user to keep its older database even after the upgradation of the app to new version of app is installed on device.Is it possible ,if yes how.Please help I am a noob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is version of db in constructor as mentioned below which tells whether app is going to update database or not. So it is not dependent on the the version of app . So if you haven't update the db version then not a problem for users who upgrade the app.

```
public class TimeTrackerDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TimeTrackerDatabase(Context context){
        super(context, "dbname.db", null, DB_Version);
    }
```